# What does "forensic practicability" mean?

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, england-and-wales, legal-terms

Herring. [*Criminal Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (8 edn, 2018)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/criminal-law-9780198811817?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 728 last para.

> By contrast with the House of Lords, the view taken here is that a conviction for a stigmatic
> offence is a sanction in its own right and that sanctions should be confined to the blameworthy.
> The non- conviction of the blameless should be a pervasive principle of substantive
> criminal law limited only by the need to theorize and practise criminal law as a system of rules
> and by the exigencies of **forensic practicability**. Those limitations entail that many ‘normal’ life
> narratives cannot afford grounds of excuse, however exculpatory the force of the narrative
> may be. But other accounts, not currently represented in standard defences, can be brought
> within the framework of substantive criminal law. If it can be done it should be done in order
> to diminish the incidence of unnecessary criminal convictions.

I can't even infer which of the [two meanings of "forensic"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/forensic)!

Answer (score 2):

[**Forensic**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/forensic) in this context means "relating to courts of law."

[**Practicability**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/practicability) includes *viability, achievability and attainability* among its synonyms.

One way of rephrasing the paragraph:

> The non- conviction of the blameless should be a pervasive principle of substantive criminal law limited only by the need to theorize and practise criminal law as a system of rules and by the exigencies of forensic practicability.

Is to say words to the effect:

> Not convicting innocent people should be a key objective, restricted only by the rule of law and the necessity for what can realistically be achieved by the courts.

Comment: Just FYI, from Nai's profile: "This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Oct 8". Probably due to low quality questions.